# Is there an icon key for PFRPG stat blocks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm a casual player of PFRPG; more often one to ape ideas from PFRPG APs for campaign arcs and encounters.

I own the Core Rulebook. That's it. I can't seem to locate the icon key for stat blocks and suspect it's provided in the Bestiary or other source book. I've poked around on Google and other places, but can't seem to find a key anywhere. Is there one or am I out of luck unless I buy more material?

An example is provided for context and clarity (which I just found a partial key in my PFRPG Beginner's Box GM Guide... and both it and C. Ross explain: Aberration, Swamp Monster)

[image: icon key found in PFRPG AP]

Comment: It's in the back of the bestiary.  Don't know if it's online ... (That's Aberration native to Temperate Swamp btw)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The image you posted is from the Bestiary (pg. 5) and the "key" is in the Creature types section.  Unfortunately neither the [Paizo PRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/monsters/creatureTypes.html) or the [d20pfsrd](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types) creature types page have those images.  I'm unaware of where else you might fight those icons.

For reference the first icon is creature "type", an aberration in your case.  The second is the terrain type, swamp in your case.  The third is "environment" (essentially climate), temperate in your case.

Comment: That's a good example of the added material that goes above and beyond the SRD sections (which also isn't covered by the OGL).

Comment: so, the icons are probably value-add, a sorta incentive to buy the books. I can't expect these to ever be available in an online and free resource.

Comment: The Icons are also given again in every Adventure Path just before the creature section. However, the icons just repeat what is written in the stat block, so they are "Aestetics Only"